# Android make contol of ADmob hide addview window after click on it

Tags: java, android, onresume, adview

I am developing an android application and I want close the window of view adds after I click on the adds window using Resume event.I put a rule in resume event but this rule make adds never show. so if there is a way to make the view adds disappears when I return to my application?
this is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (adView != null) {
         adView.destroy();
        }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the right code:

```
protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
              public void onAdOpened() {
                // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
              }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdClosed();
            }

        });


        super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use following to disappear the `view`.

```
adView.setVisibility(View.GONE):
```

set an `onClickListener` on `adView` then in `onClick` call this method.

Comment: how to make onclicklistener for adview??